# jsonschema with Postman

Tags: node.js, express, jsonschema, postman

I made a simple web api with node.js and express.js and I want to validate the schema of incomming json data to my application.

I have this very exact schema :

```
var schema = {
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"title": "Student",
"description": "Schema for student",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "first_name": {
        "description": "Firts name of the student",
        "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
        "description": "Last name of the student",
        "type": "string"
    }

},
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": ["first_name", "last_name"]

};
```

I just want to validate (for now) the first and last name. So I added "additionalProperties", so only json with a first name and a last name are valid.

When I test my app with POSTMAN with the following data, I get a lot of errors. (It should be valid)

```
{"first_name":"Test", "last_name":"Test"}
```

This should be invalid :

```
{"first_name":"Test", "last_name":"Test", "jibber":"ish"}
```

The console show about 700 lines of jsonshema validation errors :

```
{ instance: 
{ first_name: 'Test',
 last_name: 'Test',
 _id: 5451419404e5006c094057c1,
 },
schema: 
{ '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
 title: 'Student',
 description: 'Schema for student',
 type: 'object',
 properties: { first_name: [Object], last_name: [Object] },
 additionalProperties: false,
 required: [ 'first_name', 'first_name' ] },
 propertyPath: 'instance',
errors: 
[ { property: 'instance',
   message: 'Property $__ does not exist in the schema',
   schema: [Object],
   instance: 
    { first_name: 'Test',
      last_name: 'Test',
      _id: 5451419404e5006c094057c1,
       },
   stack: 'instance Property $__ does not exist in the schema' },
 { property: 'instance',
   message: 'Property isNew does not exist in the schema',
   schema: [Object],
   instance: 
    { first_name: 'Test',
      last_name: 'Test',
      _id: 5451419404e5006c094057c1,
     },
   stack: 'instance Property isNew does not exist in the schema' },
```

Are those some hidden properties that POSTMAN use ?

Comment: As a workaround, if you wanted to allow everything beginning with `$`, you could use `"patternProperties":{"^\$":{}}` - every property beginning with `$` would match (but be given no constraints).

Comment: There is a lot of properties that does not begin with $, like the last line of my error output : instance Property isNew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some testing and my body is fine. The additional properties were generated by mongoose wich casted my body to a mongoose object.

The validation must validate the page body only or it will fail.

[image: Wisdom of the ancients]